# T-SQL stored procedure returns null in code, but works in console

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, odbc

I have a stored procedure

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[get_unique_identifier]
AS
DECLARE @ret_val INT
UPDATE seq SET @ret_val = id = id + 1
RETURN @ret_val
```

that queries a table (seq) that has a single int column and single row, increments the value and then then returns it. Don't ask why I'm doing this, but in short, the idea is to simulate a PostgreSQL sequence and no, an identity column would not do the job. Anyway, this works fine in SQL Management Studio, where sequential executions of

```
DECLARE @returned INT
EXEC @returned = get_unique_identifier
SELECT @returned
```

produce the expected output. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the returned value in the application I'm working on

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("get_unique_identifier");
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OdbcParameter return_param = new OdbcParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", OdbcType.BigInt);
return_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
command.Parameters.Add(return_param);
Util.SQLExecuteParameterizedNonQuery(command);
Console.WriteLine(command.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value.ToString());
```

The output is an empty string, but the value itself is `DBNull.Value`. The `OdbcType.BigInt` is left over from some testing I was doing. It was initially `Int`.

**Edit:** This is clearly a bug with ODBC. A workaround is posted below. Don't use ODBC if you don't have do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to have to say, but this might be due to using the Odbc

I tried this using out SqlClient database object and it returned the values as expected.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ZZZ_get_unique_identifier");
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter return_param = new SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE",SqlDbType.BigInt);
return_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
command.Parameters.Add(return_param);

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbM.DefaultConnectionString);
con.Open();

command.Connection = con;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

int i = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value.ToString());
con.Close();
```

Comment: Looks like you're right. :( I just tried with SqlClient and it worked. Now I have to find a workaround for ODBC.

Comment: I managed to get it working by changing the `RETURN @ret_val` to `SELECT @ret_val` in the sp.

Comment: That should then return a table result.

Comment: Indeed. Now I can use ExecuteScalar(), which is arguably more elegant on the client side. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The return value of stored procedures is Int (32-bit), not BigInt (64-bit), but I'm not sure that this would be the problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you not tried using an output variable instead...I am jogging my memory and think that the line command.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value.ToString() could be this...The reason it worked in SQL Management Studio because you declared a variable and used it in an TSQL EXEC statement. I hope this answer somehow gives you a hint..

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Looking at it again, have you also tried Console.WriteLine(return_param.Value()) or equivalent? Why did you use ODBC and not the native SqlClient namespace?

Comment: The app was originally ported from PostgreSQL. We intend to switch to SqlClient but don't have time right now.